# Repeated set of UUIDs from java's UUID.randomUUID()

Tags: linux, java, random

We have observed that set of almost 200,000 UUIDs has replayed two months apart, and I'm wondering if anyone has seen anything similar.

The UUIDs are generated using UUID.randomUUID().  In digging into this (looking at java source), randomUUID() uses SecureRandom() under the hood, which in turn is using NativePRNG.  It is my understanding that NativePRNG uses /dev/urandom to acquire its seed.  The implication of course is baffling - that somehow /dev/urandom returned the same seed to NativePRNG two months apart.  From what I can tell, once instantiated the PRNG does not re-seed.  This is a long running job which s listening for messages and using a UUID as an ID for it.  The pseudocode is simply:

`< receive message>
String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
String fname = h.composeArtifact(uuid);`

The OS is Centos 6, on an AWS EC2 instance running JDK1.6.  Is this something that anyone has seen/experienced in the past?  Seems like the kind of thing that should 'never happen'...

Comment: I'm not sure this is a security question, but a java internals question.

Comment: Were they generated from a newly created instance in both cases?

Comment: What if whatever internal storage used to keep this `UUID seed` thingy is a file that is managed via Chef / Puppet / part of a VM snapshot? I think it's legitimate to ask how this allegedly unique seed is stored and manipulated and whether there is a chance for the ways in which the OS is managed to cause it to be reset to a past value. Equally interesting is the question of whether the PRNG used in Java is likely to loop over a small subset of values, how often and how an attacker would detect that.

Comment: You say "a set of 200k UUIDs" -- out of how many?

Comment: I am just seeing exactly the same. I was just running a test `@Test(threadPoolSize = 50, invocationCount = 2)` using `testng`. When I set `invocationCount = 1`, my test runs fine. But when I set it to 2 or more for simultaneous parallel threads, the test failed. I've been digging in an realized the ids I generated for my test objects using `UUID.randomUUID()` were exactly the same in all threads. I was able to circumvent this by adding a random delay for each thread. In other words: If threads run exactly at the same time, the UUID being generated is the same in all threads.

Answer (score 20):

From JDK 1.6 source, indeed, `UUID.randomUUID()` feeds on a `java.util.SecureRandom` instance. If you got a repeated sequence of UUID, then either you got very lucky (or very unlucky, depending on your point of view), or someone played with VM snapshots, or there is something fishy in your Java configuration.

When taking a VM snapshot, you record the complete live state of the machine, processes and RAM included. If there was a live process with an already instantiated `SecureRandom` instance, restoring the snapshot will bring back that state, so the sequence of random values output by that `SecureRandom` will be the same each time a restore occurs, until the `SecureRandom` reseeds itself from `/dev/urandom` (`/dev/urandom` continuously gathers "random" physical events, but these won't impact the `SecureRandom` state until the next reseeding).

The Java configuration may impact `SecureRandom`, in that `SecureRandom` is NOT a PRNG, but a shell around an instance of `SecureRandomSpi` provided by a duly registered cryptographic provider. Sun's JDK comes with a default implementation that *normally* feeds on the system's resources (`/dev/urandom` on Linux). However, this can be configured; lookup the `java.security.egd` system property, and also the `securerandom.source` property in the `java.security` file. The default provider may also be replaced altogether with an alternate implementation that does things differently (and possibly very poorly). See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/14387/655) for some details. Verifying what random source is indeed used can be a bit complex, but you could try launching your process with [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace), which will show system calls, hence whether `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` is opened at some point.

If your Java configuration is fine, *and* there was no game with VM snapshots, *and* you are sure that you indeed got the same sequence of UUID as previously, then you really *really* should have bought a Powerball ticket instead (but I do not honestly believe in this scenario).

Comment: I was just shocked to discover that I apparently downvoted this answer completely without intending to, and I can't reverse it because it was too long ago. I must have idly clicked while I was reading. Not that it's going to negatively impact your 203k reputation score, but sorry, wasn't intended.

Comment: @CraigTullis: You can always do a small edit to lift the restriction and then remove the down vote. It should not be a habit but it is one way to reverse a mistake/correct something after it has been changed. I just added a missing word, so if you feel like it, you could probably remove your downvote now. :)